# TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDrawerNavigator' of undefined

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

When I' using the react navigation version 6.1.1. I face this error.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDrawerNavigator' of undefined

I have import the createDrawerNavigator from @react-navigation/drawer. But When I start the app the I saw this error  TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDrawerNavigator' of undefined. How can I solve this error?

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ0kJ.png)

Comment: Are you running from cmd or android studio?

Comment: @JatinBhuva I am using PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

We have to import the gesture handler in the main index file. like this

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Answer (score 0):

install "react-native-reanimated" and config your bable.config file

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
  ],
};
```

and then

```
pod install
yarn start --reset-cache
```

Comment: I've already installed react-native-reanimated and also added this code to the babel.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Open your android folder in android studio, then run from there.