# TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDrawerNavigator' of undefined with @react-navigation/drawer@6.6.3

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I am getting the following when I try to use the drawer navigator. This seems to be the same error as found in [this existing stack overflow item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74859163/typeerror-cannot-read-property-createdrawernavigator-of-undefined)

```
    This error is located at:
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in FirstReactNative(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
    ** ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDrawerNavigator' of undefined**

    This error is located at:
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in FirstReactNative(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

## I was following both:

- [installation instructions for react-navigaton](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started)
- [installation instructions for the drawer navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator#installation)

Here is my setup after following the directions:

---

### package.json

```js
     "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.10.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.24.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0"
      },
```

---

### babel.config.js

```js
    module.exports = {
      presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
      plugins: ["@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx", "react-native-reanimated/plugin"]
    };
```

---

### index.js

```js
     import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
    import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
    import App from './App';
    import {name as appName} from './app.json';

    AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

---

### android\app\src\main\java\com\firstreactnative\MainActivity.java

```java
    package com.firstreactnative;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
    import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
    import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
    import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate;
    
    public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    //....
        @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(null);
      }
    }
```

---

### app.js

```js
    import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
    import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';    
    
    function App(): JSX.Element {
    
      const Stack = createStackNavigator();
      const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

    }
```

## Other info

- createStackNavigator() works just fine
- the error occurs when the createDrawerNavigator() is called.
- You don't have to actually try to use a navigator.

Comment: According to your package.json, you haven't install the required library `react-native-reanimated`. Please install and try again.

Comment: This solves my problem. Thank you. I did have to do `npm start -- --reset-cache` in order to allow the build process to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting kiuQ's response as the answer.

According to your package.json, you haven't install the required library react-native-reanimated. Please install and try again. – kiuQ

I did have to do `npm start -- --reset-cache` in order to allow the build process to work.